# Tor ControlPort HashPassword

Tags: node.js, hash, terminal, npm, tor

After I generate a hashed password and I try to run my `tor-request` module and I keep getting error. I have updated the new pass in my torr file, in my script and restarted tor. I still get this error and don't know how to fix. I see it was a commmon bug a few years ago but no soltuion. Thanks

`Uncaught Error: Error communicating with Tor ControlPort
515 Authentication failed: Password did not match HashedControlPassword value from configuration. Maybe you tried a plain text password? If so, the standard requires that you put it in double quotes.`

torr file

`HashedControlPassword 16:142<MoreNumbers>49`

## Matches my pass generated through command line arg.

Comment: During authentication is the password enclosed in quotes?  This error would indicate it wasn't which it should be.  Try `AUTHENTICATE "the password given on the command line"`

Comment: How did you generate the password?

Comment: `tor --hash-password myPasswordHere`

Comment: @drew010, Authenticate - command not found

Comment: Hmm, well authenticate is definitely a command so if you're getting that then something is wrong.

Comment: @qbi, I tried `tor --hash-password "myPasswordHere"` as well.. Still quote error